# Using a PNG image as mask for GrabCut

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have a png image with green and red lines and transparent background, which I need to use is as a mask for executing GrabCut. But I get unexpected results. Here's my code:

```
//find the mask
Mat mask;
mask.create( image.size(), CV_8UC1);
mask.setTo(Scalar::all(GC_BGD));
Mat maskImg = imread("messi5.png");

for(int i=0; i<maskImg.cols; i++)    
    for(int j=0; j<maskImg.rows; j++)    
    {               
        //if it's red, make it white
        if ((int)maskImg.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[0]==0 && (int)maskImg.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[1] == 0 && (int)maskImg.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[2] == 255) {

            mask.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[0]= GC_BGD;
            mask.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[1] = GC_BGD;
            mask.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[2] = GC_BGD;
        }           

        //if it's green, make it black
        if ((int)maskImg.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[0]==0 && (int)maskImg.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[1] == 255 && (int)maskImg.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[2] == 0) {    
            mask.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[0] = GC_FGD;
            mask.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[1] = GC_FGD;
            mask.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[2] = GC_FGD;
        }
    }

 ...
```

Here's the output: http://prntscr.com/40kt4e. I guess it's like there's no rectangle, it only sees the GC_FGD pixels, everything else is considered BG. And it looks somehow scaled, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was trying to say in

[GrabCut reading mask from PNG file in OpenCV (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627406/grabcut-reading-mask-from-png-file-in-opencv-c/24628394#comment38173128_24628394)

that your using the 3 channel accessor for a 1 channel image.  this will mess things up a little, use the 1 channel version for the 1 channel mask:

```
    Mat image;
    image= cv::imread(file);

    //everything outside this box will be set to def. 
    //background GC_BGD, clearly from the image you can see that the players legs are outside the box, 
    //so this will cause problems. you need to either change the box, 
    //such that everything is outside the box is the background, or use your mask to scribble on the players legs in green.  
    cv::Rect rectangle(startX, startY, width, height);  
    cv::Mat bgModel,fgModel;

    //find the mask
    Mat mask;
    mask.create( image.size(), CV_8UC1);  //CV_8UC1 is single channel
    mask.setTo(Scalar::all(GC_BGD));  //you have set it to all def. background 

    Mat maskImg = imread("messi5.png");


    for(int i=0; i<maskImg.cols; i++)    
        for(int j=0; j<maskImg.rows; j++)    
        {               
            //if it's red, make it black
            if ((int)maskImg.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[0]==0 && (int)maskImg.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[1] == 0 && (int)maskImg.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[2] == 255) {

                //the whole mask is black so this is redundant
                mask.at<uchar>(j,i)= GC_BGD;  //GC_BGD := 0 := black 

            }           

            //if it's green, make it white
            if ((int)maskImg.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[0]==0 && (int)maskImg.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[1] == 255 && (int)maskImg.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[2] == 0) {    

                    mask.at<uchar>(j,i) = GC_FGD; //GC_FGD:= 1 := white 

            }
        }
```

For more efficient code for looping over images please see:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html

The LUT function my do the trick here:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#the-core-function

Comment: This works great, but it's very slow for large resolution images? Do you have some suggestion for improving the performance, other then making it run on the GPU?

Comment: Hi, if you mean just that loop, then you can access data directly, rather than using the .at function.  If you mean GrabCut then i'm afraid not, as this would mean speeding up graph-cut, which is essentially max-flow, so you entering heavy comp. science work there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963617/fastest-way-to-extract-individual-pixel-data

Comment: @QUED I think I should try parallel programming, I think that's the best way to increase performance. Can you give me any directions, just to know where to start?

Comment: Hi, if you really want to do that then perhaps start here: Parallel and Distributed Graph Cuts by Dual Decomposition, http://lup.lub.lu.se/luur/download?func=downloadFile&recordOId=1567612&fileOId=1580403. Also consider "cudacuts" and also multi-scale pyramids with propagation of solution from coarse to fine.   Otherwise maybe look at alternatives to interactive image segmentation that don't use graph cut.