# Using Mask Canvas image for grabcut in OpenCV.js

Tags: javascript, opencv

I am trying to get more accuracy with the Grabcut in OpenCV.js by setting mask image with options GC_BGD et GC_FGD. To put it simple, I am trying to achieve the same thing as in the Python documentation (https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/d83/tutorial_py_grabcut.html) but in Javascript.

Here is the image I have with the white dash, the selected area:
[image]

I want to readjust the selection by setting the remaining non-selected part of the hat as foreground and the blue leather as a background (as an example purpose):
So, in another canvas layer, I draw a marker green in the part of the hat I want to set as GC_FGD and red for GC_BGD.

[image]
[image]

Here is my code to implement the mask

```
    let src = cv.imread("canvasInput");
    cv.cvtColor(src, src, cv.COLOR_RGBA2RGB, 0);
    let newmask = cv.imread("canvasAdjust", 0);
    let mask = new cv.Mat(newmask.rows, newmask.cols, newmask.type());
    let bgdModel = new cv.Mat();
    let fgdModel = new cv.Mat();
    let rect = new cv.Rect();

    for (let i = 0; i < newmask.rows; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < newmask.cols; j++) {
         if (newmask.ucharPtr(i, j)[1] == 128) {
           // if green, tell the mask that it's foreground
           mask.ucharPtr(i, j)[0] = cv.GC_FGD;
           mask.ucharPtr(i, j)[1] = cv.GC_FGD;
           mask.ucharPtr(i, j)[2] = cv.GC_FGD;
         }
        if (newmask.ucharPtr(i, j)[0] == 255) {
           // if red, tell the mask that it's background
           mask.ucharPtr(i, j)[0] = cv.GC_BGD;
           mask.ucharPtr(i, j)[1] = cv.GC_BGD;
           mask.ucharPtr(i, j)[2] = cv.GC_BGD;
        }
      }
    }

   cv.grabCut(src, mask, rect, bgdModel, fgdModel, 1, cv.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT);
```

`CanvasOrigin` is the canvas with the picture. `CanvasAdjust` the canvas with the markers and `CanvasOutput` the output where I get the current selection + the adjustement.

**My question is, how do I set the mask so that grabcut take it into account for the selection?**

I got some inspiration from openCV Java here: [How to set a mask image for grabCut in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111716/how-to-set-a-mask-image-for-grabcut-in-opencv) and openCV C++ here: [Using a PNG image as mask for GrabCut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24631988/using-a-png-image-as-mask-for-grabcut) but I can't get it to work .

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: here is a simplistic fiddle I created to illustrate my example: https://jsfiddle.net/knighto05/kxpfr106/67/

Comment: did you ever solve this issue??

Comment: @ChannelJuanNews yes but it was 2 months ago and my memory failed me. I'll search for the code and I'll post it in the answer

Comment: if you could post your solution, I would be very appreciative as I am trying to do the exact same thing! 

Thank you :)

Comment: were you able to find the solution?

Comment: @ChannelJuanNews Yes actually! but tangled with other code logics! I'm trying to separate it but got errors like before. It was our senior's code so that's why I'm struggling but I'll may get it right today